# How to add multiple inputs (knobs) to a single slider?

Tags: r, shiny, slider, uislider, jquery-ui-slider

I am building a shiny app with a slider. But I notice there is either a slider with 1 knob or a slider with 2 knobs that display the range. However, I need to build a single slider with 3 knobs and all the 3 knobs should pass 3 different input values and should be independent of each other (same slider scale). How do I achieve this in R Shiny or Jquery?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using Java Script. Just update the Values with three values and it will display 3 knobs on the slider